# What does the argument mean in fig.add_subplot(111)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, figure

Sometimes I come across code such as this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image: Example plot produced by the included code]

I've been reading the documentation like crazy but I can't find an explanation for the `111`. sometimes I see a `212`.

What does the argument of `fig.add_subplot()` mean?

Answer (score 610, accepted):

These are subplot grid parameters encoded as a single integer. For example, "111" means "1x1 grid, first subplot" and "234" means "2x3 grid, 4th subplot".

Alternative form for `add_subplot(111)` is `add_subplot(1, 1, 1)`.

Answer (score 625):

I think this would be best explained by the following picture:

[image]

To initialize the above, one would type:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(221)   #top left
fig.add_subplot(222)   #top right
fig.add_subplot(223)   #bottom left
fig.add_subplot(224)   #bottom right 
plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why are there 3 parameters and not 2.

Comment: I cant see any difference on images, what is the difference that i cant see?

Comment: @AbbasElma Checkout the overall place in which the subplot is placed on the plot.

Comment: @UpulieHandalage ooooh the all of 4 images actually one big plot. Not easy to spot thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 52):

The answer from Constantin is spot on but for more background this behavior is inherited from Matlab.

The Matlab behavior is explained in the [Figure Setup - Displaying Multiple Plots per Figure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) section of the Matlab documentation.

> subplot(m,n,i) breaks the figure window into an m-by-n matrix of small
>   subplots and selects the ithe subplot for the current plot. The plots
>   are numbered along the top row of the figure window, then the second
>   row, and so forth.

Answer (score 35):

My solution is

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)   #top and bottom left
fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)   #top right
fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)   #bottom right 
plt.show()
```

[image: 2x2 grid with 1 and 3 merge]

Answer (score 32):

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.subplot(3,2,1)
plt.subplot(3,2,3)
plt.subplot(3,2,5)
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
```

The first code creates the first subplot in a layout that has 3 rows and 2 columns.

The three graphs in the first column denote the 3 rows. The second plot comes just below the first plot in the same column and so on.

The last two plots have arguments `(2, 2)` denoting that the second column has only two rows, the position parameters move row wise.

Answer (score 20):

The **add_subplot()** method has several call signatures:

1. `add_subplot(nrows, ncols, index, **kwargs)`
2. `add_subplot(pos, **kwargs)`
3. `add_subplot(ax)`
4. `add_subplot()` <-- since 3.1.0

---

## Calls 1 and 2:

Calls 1 and 2 achieve the same thing as one another (up to a limit, explained below). Think of them as first specifying the grid layout with their **first 2 numbers** (2x2, 1x8, 3x4, etc), e.g:

```py
f.add_subplot(3,4,1) 
# is equivalent to:
f.add_subplot(341)
```

Both produce a subplot arrangement of (3 x 4 = 12) subplots in 3 rows and 4 columns. The **third number** in each call indicates which axis object to return, starting from **1 at the top left, increasing to the right**.

This code illustrates the limitations of using call 2:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_and_text(axis, text):
  '''Simple function to add a straight line
  and text to an axis object'''
  axis.plot([0,1],[0,1])
  axis.text(0.02, 0.9, text)

f = plt.figure()
f2 = plt.figure()

_max = 12
for i in range(_max):
  axis = f.add_subplot(3,4,i+1, fc=(0,0,0,i/(_max*2)), xticks=[], yticks=[])
  plot_and_text(axis,chr(i+97) + ') ' + '3,4,' +str(i+1))

  # If this check isn't in place, a 
  # ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 15, not 0 is raised
  if i < 9:
    axis = f2.add_subplot(341+i, fc=(0,0,0,i/(_max*2)), xticks=[], yticks=[])
    plot_and_text(axis,chr(i+97) + ') ' + str(341+i))

f.tight_layout()
f2.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: subplots]

You can see with **call 1 on the LHS** you can return any axis object, however with **call 2 on the RHS** you can only return up to index = 9 rendering subplots j), k), and l) inaccessible using this call.

I.e it illustrates this point [from the documentation:](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-subplot)

> pos is a three digit integer, where the first digit is the number of rows, the second the number of columns, and the third the index of the subplot. i.e. fig.add_subplot(235) is the same as fig.add_subplot(2, 3, 5). **Note that all integers must be less than 10 for this form to work**.

---

## Call 3

> In rare circumstances, add_subplot may be called with a single argument, a subplot axes instance already created in the present figure but not in the figure's list of axes.

---

## Call 4 (since 3.1.0):

> If no positional arguments are passed, defaults to (1, 1, 1).

i.e., reproducing the call `fig.add_subplot(111)` in the question. This essentially sets up a 1 x 1 grid of subplots and returns the first (and only) axis object in the grid.

Answer (score 17):

`fig.add_subplot(ROW,COLUMN,POSITION)`

- ROW=number of rows
- COLUMN=number of columns
- POSITION= position of the graph you are plotting

***Examples***

```
`fig.add_subplot(111)` #There is only one subplot or graph  
`fig.add_subplot(211)`  *and*  `fig.add_subplot(212)`
```

There are total 2 rows,1 column therefore 2 subgraphs can be plotted. Its location is 1st. There are total 2 rows,1 column therefore 2 subgraphs can be plotted.Its location is 2nd