# Two y-axis on the left side of the figure

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot curves with different y-axis that share the same x-axis. I have used the `twinx` function before, but it plot them on different side of the figure. Is there a way to plot both of them on the left hand side. I am looking for something like the following[image]

but with both the axis on the same side. The code for the above example is [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html).

On a different not, can one plot the curves in some particular order, as z-order do not work for `twinx`

Comment: Please include the example code to generate this, links rot

Comment: As it was a standard matplotlib example, I put the link. My question was also different, and I put the figure to make it clear.

Comment: Use zorder on the axes, not on the lines.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Whats shown in red is the default `twinx()` behavior. The extra modification in the [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html) applies to whats shown in green.

You can modify both new axes similar as the `green` one, but select the `left` spine and apply a negative offset. So add/change the example with:

```
par1.spines["left"].set_position(("axes", -0.4)) # red one
par2.spines["left"].set_position(("axes", -0.2)) # green one

make_patch_spines_invisible(par1)
make_patch_spines_invisible(par2)

par1.spines["left"].set_visible(True)
par1.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
par1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

par2.spines["left"].set_visible(True)
par2.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
par2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
```

[image]

The `zorder` from lines is only taken into account within the axes (or so it appears?), since you have separate axes on top of each other, you should modify the `zorder` of the axes:

```
host.set_zorder(1)
par1.set_zorder(2)
par2.set_zorder(3)
```

Note that the `host` has a white background, placing it on top will hide the other lines unless you set the background to be transparent.

Comment: What are the objects par1, par2?

Comment: They are `axes` objects and come from the example which imsc is showing, see: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html
I have only shown the modifications, maybe imsc can include the original code in his opening post.

Comment: You can also change the color of the spines themselves with: `host.spines["left"].set_edgecolor(p1.get_color())`, etc.

Comment: I note that this same approach will work with the approach to add secondary axes (a.k.a. parasite axes) using the standard matplotlib module demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45925049/8508004). I describe how to do this as well as use the modern `subplots()` method on conjunction with it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103166/multiple-axis-in-matplotlib-with-different-scales#comment82074734_45925049)

Comment: Note that the spine is just the line segment. To selectively hide the ticks: `par1.tick_params(left=False)`. To selectively hide the tick labels: `par1.tick_params(labelleft=False)`.

Answer (score 7):

Here a function to make it automatically for any of the sides in case someone need it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plotting_several_axis(variables, positions, colors, ylabels, xlabel, yaxislabels, 
                          fontsize=12, y_axis_dist = 0.2, figsize=(7,5)):
    """
    plotting_several_axis(variables, positions, colors, ylabels, xlabel, yaxislabels, 
                          fontsize=12, y_axis_dist = 0.2, figsize=(7,5))

    Example:

    a1 = np.arange(1, 100, 1)
    a2 = np.arange(1, 100, 1)
    a = [a1, a2]
    b = [i**2 for i in a]
    c = [i/5 for i in b]
    d = [i*8 for i in c]
    e = [i+5 for i in d]
    variables = [a, b, c, d, e]

    positions = ['right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right']
    colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red', 'magenta', 'brown']
    ylabels = ['potatoes', 'rice', 'tomatoes', 'juice', 'cotton']
    xlabel = 'price'
    yaxislabels = ['item', 'kg', 'bunch', 'Liters', 'cm3']

    """
    def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
        ax.set_frame_on(True)
        ax.patch.set_visible(False)
        for sp in ax.spines.values():
            sp.set_visible(False)


    fig, host = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)


    ###### HOST PLOTTING
    tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5, labelsize=fontsize)


    p1, = host.plot(variables[0][0], variables[0][1], colors[0], label=ylabels[0])
    host.set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize=fontsize)
    host.set_ylabel(yaxislabels[0], fontsize=fontsize)
    host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
    host.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
    host.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)
    # host.set_xlim(0, 2)

    lines = [p1]

#     y_axis_dist = 0.2
    inc_r = 1
    inc_l = -y_axis_dist

    for ix, i in enumerate(variables):


        if ix != 0:
            par = host.twinx()
            if positions[ix] == 'right':
                par.spines[positions[ix]].set_position(("axes", inc_r))
                inc_r += y_axis_dist
            elif positions[ix] == 'left':
                par.spines[positions[ix]].set_position(("axes", inc_l))
                inc_l -= y_axis_dist

            make_patch_spines_invisible(par)
            par.spines[positions[ix]].set_visible(True)
            par.yaxis.set_label_position(positions[ix])
            par.yaxis.set_ticks_position(positions[ix])
            p, = par.plot(variables[ix][0], variables[ix][1], colors[ix], label=ylabels[ix])
            par.set_ylabel(yaxislabels[ix], fontsize=fontsize)
            par.yaxis.label.set_color(p.get_color())
            par.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p.get_color(), **tkw)
            lines.append(p)

    host.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines], fontsize=fontsize, loc='lower right')
    plt.savefig("example.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")

    plt.show()

a1 = np.arange(1, 100, 1)
a2 = np.arange(1, 100, 1)
a = [a1, a2]
b = [i**2 for i in a]
c = [i/5 for i in b]
d = [i*8 for i in c]
e = [i+5 for i in d]
variables = [a, b, c, d, e]

positions = ['right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right']
colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red', 'magenta', 'brown']
ylabels = ['potatoes', 'rice', 'tomatoes', 'juice', 'cotton']
xlabel = 'price'
yaxislabels = ['item', 'kg', 'bunch', 'Liters', 'cm3']

plotting_several_axis(variables, positions, colors, ylabels, xlabel, yaxislabels, y_axis_dist=0.2)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: axislabels = ['item', 'kg', 'bunch', 'Liters', 'cm3']
positions = ['right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right']

But in the picture, item and kg are in the same side (left). Code needs some changes?

Comment: @user394430 I just tried it and it generates the same exact plot. It uses matplotlib version 3.2.2.

Comment: @Malj90, Hmmm... running on MPL 3.2.1, I can recreate your plot. I do not know what version of MPL I was running when I first tried your code. I've deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @Malj90 Absolutely remarkable, thanks so much for sharing this great piece of code!