# Can Gnuplot put Two y-axis on the left hand side of a plot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to create a plot which has two independent y-axes on the left hand side, i.e. sharing the same x-axis. Is this possible in Gnuplot? I'm aware that it can be done with python for example.

Comment: please see this thread for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146652/two-y-axis-on-the-left-side-of-the-figure

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the plot on gnuplot's standard x1y1 and x1y2 axes, and then add the extra axis with `multiplot`.

This example here is not perfect, but should give you an idea how to do it. As Christoph said, it's a bit fiddly:

```
set multiplot
set lmargin at scr 0.2
set bmargin at scr 0.1 # fix bottom margin
set y2range [0:20]     
plot x, 2*x axes x1y2  # this is your actual plot

set lmargin at scr 0.1
set yrange [0:20]    # set yrange to the same as y2 in the first plot
set border 2         # switch off all borders except the left   
unset xtics          # switch off the stray xtics
plot -1000 notitle   # plot something outside of the y(2)range
unset multi
```

Comment: Thanks Karl. I will try messing with this today.