# Sharing a yaxis label with two of three subplots in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which produces the plot shown.

```
mport matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

One = range(1,10)
Two = range(5, 14) 
l = len(One)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, height_ratios=[5, 3, 3]) 

ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax0.bar(range(l), Two)
plt.ylabel("Number of occurrence")

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax0)
ax1.bar(range(l), Two)

ax2 =  plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax2.bar(range(l), One)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I want the ylabel (" Number of occurrence") to be shared between first and second plot, that is, it should occur in the center left of first and second plot. How do I do that?

Comment: English correction: do you mean "Number of occurences"?

Answer (score 4):

The best way I can think of is to add the text to the figure itself and position it at the center (figure coordinates of 0.5) like so

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

One = range(1,10)
Two = range(5, 14)
l = len(One)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, height_ratios=[5, 3, 3])

ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax0.bar(range(l), Two)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax0)
ax1.bar(range(l), Two)

ax2 =  plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax2.bar(range(l), One)

fig.text(0.075, 0.5, "Number of occurrence", rotation="vertical", va="center")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also adjust the position manually, using the `y` parameter of `ylabel`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

One = range(1,10)
Two = range(5, 14) 
l = len(One)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, height_ratios=[5, 3, 3]) 

ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax0.bar(range(l), Two)
plt.ylabel("Number of occurrence", y=-0.8)          ##  ← ← ← HERE

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax0)
ax1.bar(range(l), Two)

ax2 =  plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax2.bar(range(l), One)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

not a very sophisticated solution, but would this work?  Replace

```
plt.ylabel("Number of occurrence")
```

with

```
plt.ylabel("Number of occurrence", verticalalignment = 'top')
```

**[edit]**

for my version of 64 bit python (2.7.3) I needed to make a small change

```
plt.ylabel("Number of occurrence", horizontalalignment = 'right')
```

here's what it looks like to me, is this not what you want?

[image]

Comment: This does not put the label in the center of first two plots.

Comment: @DurgaDatta I've added what the image looks like on my computer, is that the requirement?

Comment: This would do my job. However, I do not get this sort of image in my machine. Where do you put that line? Should it matter?

Comment: just replace you're ylabel with the one I have above

Comment: I tried it on python 2.7.3 32 bit and it worked, when I tried it on 2.7.3 64 bit it didn't.  If you are using 64 bit then try `plt.ylabel("Number of occurrence", horizontalalignment = 'right')` instead

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is more of creating multiple-axis if said in the right terms. I would like to point you to the question I asked and the answer I received which gives you the solution to create multiple-axis for the plot.

Link to the similar problem solution in Matplotlib:
[Using Multiple Axis](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html)

Link to the other related question is:[multiple axis in matplotlib with different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103166/multiple-axis-in-matplotlib-with-different-scales)