# Subplotting subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am creating two plots using matplotlib, each of them is a subplot showing two metrics on the same axis.

I'm trying to run them so they show as two charts but in one graphic, so that when I save the graphic I see both plots. At the moment, running the second plot overwrites the first in memory so I can only ever save the second.

How can I plot them together?

My code is below.

```
plot1 = plt.figure()
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(dfSat['time'],dfSat['wind_at_altitude'], 'b-', label = "speed", linewidth = 5.0)
plt.title('Wind Speeds - Saturday - {}'.format(windloc))
plt.xlabel('Time of day')
plt.ylabel('Wind speed (mph)')
ax1.plot(dfSat['time'],dfSat['gust_at_altitude'], 'r-', label = "gust", linewidth = 5.0)
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
ax1.text(0.05, 0.95, calcmeassat, transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=30,
        verticalalignment='top')
plt.ylim((0,100))

plot2 = plt.figure()
fig,ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(dfSun['time'],dfSun['wind_at_altitude'], 'b-', label = "speed", linewidth = 5.0)
plt.title('Wind Speeds - Sunday - {}'.format(windloc))
plt.xlabel('Time of day')
plt.ylabel('Wind speed (mph)')
ax2.plot(dfSun['time'],dfSun['gust_at_altitude'], 'r-', label = "gust", linewidth = 5.0)
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
ax2.text(0.05, 0.95, calcmeassun, transform=ax2.transAxes, fontsize=30,
        verticalalignment='top')
plt.ylim((0,100))
```

Comment: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)` or similar. Please read the [matplotlib tutorial on generating subplots.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As mentioned, in your case you only need one level of subplots, e.g., `nrows=1, ncols=2`.
- **However,** in matplotlib 3.4+ there is such a thing as "subplotting subplots" called **[subfigures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subfigures),** which makes it easier to implement nested layouts, e.g.:

  - [How to create row titles for subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68209152/13138364)
  - [How to share colorbars within some subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54134181/13138364)
  - [How to share xlabels within some subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553015/13138364)

#### Subplots

For your simpler use case, create 1x2 subplots with `ax1` on the left and `ax2` on the right:

[image: subplots]

```
# create 1x2 subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(16, 4))

# plot saturdays on the left
dfSat.plot(ax=ax1, x='date', y='temp_min')
dfSat.plot(ax=ax1, x='date', y='temp_max')
ax1.set_ylim(-20, 50)
ax1.set_title('Saturdays')

# plot sundays on the right
dfSun.plot(ax=ax2, x='date', y='temp_min')
dfSun.plot(ax=ax2, x='date', y='temp_max')
ax2.set_ylim(-20, 50)
ax2.set_title('Sundays')
```

#### Subfigures

Say you want something more complicated like having the left side show 2012 with its own `suptitle` and right side to show 2015 with its own `suptitle`.

Create 1x2 subfigures (left `subfig_l` and right `subfig_r`) with 2x1 subplots on the left (top `ax_lt` and bottom `ax_lb`) and 2x1 subplots on the right (top `ax_rt` and bottom `ax_rb`):

[image: subfigures]

```
# create 1x2 subfigures
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(12, 5))
(subfig_l, subfig_r) = fig.subfigures(nrows=1, ncols=2, wspace=0.07)

# create top/box axes in left subfig
(ax_lt, ax_lb) = subfig_l.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

# plot 2012 saturdays on left-top axes
dfSat12 = dfSat.loc[dfSat['date'].dt.year.eq(2012)]
dfSat12.plot(ax=ax_lt, x='date', y='temp_min')
dfSat12.plot(ax=ax_lt, x='date', y='temp_max')
ax_lt.set_ylim(-20, 50)
ax_lt.set_ylabel('Saturdays')

# plot 2012 sundays on left-top axes
dfSun12 = dfSun.loc[dfSun['date'].dt.year.eq(2012)]
dfSun12.plot(ax=ax_lb, x='date', y='temp_min')
dfSun12.plot(ax=ax_lb, x='date', y='temp_max')
ax_lb.set_ylim(-20, 50)
ax_lb.set_ylabel('Sundays')

# set suptitle for left subfig
subfig_l.suptitle('2012', size='x-large', weight='bold')

# create top/box axes in right subfig
(ax_rt, ax_rb) = subfig_r.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

# plot 2015 saturdays on left-top axes
dfSat15 = dfSat.loc[dfSat['date'].dt.year.eq(2015)]
dfSat15.plot(ax=ax_rt, x='date', y='temp_min')
dfSat15.plot(ax=ax_rt, x='date', y='temp_max')
ax_rt.set_ylim(-20, 50)
ax_rt.set_ylabel('Saturdays')

# plot 2015 sundays on left-top axes
dfSun15 = dfSun.loc[dfSun['date'].dt.year.eq(2015)]
dfSun15.plot(ax=ax_rb, x='date', y='temp_min')
dfSun15.plot(ax=ax_rb, x='date', y='temp_max')
ax_rb.set_ylim(-20, 50)
ax_rb.set_ylabel('Sundays')

# set suptitle for right subfig
subfig_r.suptitle('2015', size='x-large', weight='bold')
```

---

Sample data for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

df = data.seattle_weather()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
dfSat = df.loc[df['date'].dt.weekday.eq(5)]
dfSun = df.loc[df['date'].dt.weekday.eq(6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that. Subplots are what they are called; **plots** inside a **main** plot.

That means if you need two subplots; then you need one plot containing two subplots in it.

```
# figure object NOT plot object
# useful when you want only one plot NO subplots
fig = plt.figure() 

# 2 subplots inside 1 plot
# 1 row, 2 columns
fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(1, 2)

# then call plotting method on each axis object to
# create plot on that subplot
sns.histplot(...., ax=ax1)
sns.violinplot(..., ax=ax2)

# or using matplotlib like this
ax1.plot()
ax2.plot()
```

Learn more about [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)