# Multiple y-axis conversion scales

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels, data-conversion

[image: Conversion scale with 'parasitic' parallel y axis]

[image: Conversion scale with shared y axis]

Hi

I'm trying to create plots which incorporate parallel conversion scales for two sets of units on the y-axis; using the two different styles of:

1. offset ('parasitic') y-axes and
2. overlaid/shared y-axes

to replicate the style of the left-hand y-axes in the attached example images.

I'd like to find the simplest generic way of producing both of the above example plots, which also allows me to generate the y-axis conversion scales by defining the relationship between the two sets of units as a function (in this example: mmHg = kPa * 7.5).

If it's possible to add the third right-hand y axes (vapour concentration and water content) shown in these examples, which are unrelated to the left hand scales, this would be a bonus.

I've read related stackoverflow.com postings and examples on using multiple x and y axes using the twinx and twiny functions - e.g. 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325232/two-corresponding-y-axis) - as well as the Matplotlib cookbook, but I can't find an example which addresses this particular problem.

I'd be very grateful for any minimal working examples or links.

I'm using Matplotlib in Spyder 2.2.1 / Python 2.7.5

Many thanks in anticipation

Dave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first plot, I recommend `axisartist`. The automatic scaling of the two `y`-axis on the left-hand-side is achieved through a simple scaling factor that applies to the specified `y`-limits. This first example is based on the explanations on [parasite axes](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html):

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# initialize the three axis:
host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()

# secify the offset for the left-most axis:
offset = -60
new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="left", axes=par2, offset=(offset, 0))
par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

# data ratio for the two left y-axis:
y3_to_y1 = 1/7.5

# y-axis limits:
YLIM = [0.0, 150.0,
        0.0, 150.0]

# set up dummy data
x = np.linspace(0,70.0,70.0)
y1 = np.asarray([xi**2.0*0.032653 for xi in x])
y2 = np.asarray([xi**2.0*0.02857 for xi in x])

# plot data on y1 and y2, respectively:
host.plot(x,y1,'b')
par1.plot(x,y2,'r')

# specify the axis limits:
host.set_xlim(0.0,70.0)
host.set_ylim(YLIM[0],YLIM[1])
par1.set_ylim(YLIM[2],YLIM[3])

# when specifying the limits for the left-most y-axis
# you utilize the conversion factor:
par2.set_ylim(YLIM[2]*y3_to_y1,YLIM[3]*y3_to_y1)

# set y-ticks, use np.arange for defined deltas
# add a small increment to the last ylim value
# to ensure that the last value will be a tick
host.set_yticks(np.arange(YLIM[0],YLIM[1]+0.001,10.0))
par1.set_yticks(np.arange(YLIM[2],YLIM[3]+0.001,10.0))
par2.set_yticks(np.arange(YLIM[2]*y3_to_y1,YLIM[3]*y3_to_y1+0.001, 2.0))

plt.show()
```

You will end up with this plot:

[image: first figure]

You can try to modify the above example to give you the second plot, too. One idea is, to reduce `offset` to zero. However, with the `axisartist`, certain tick functions [are not supported](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html). One of them is specifying if the ticks go inside or outside the axis.
Therefore, for the second plot, the following example (based on [matplotlib: overlay plots with different scales?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733693/matplotlib-overlay-plots-with-different-scales)) is appropriate.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# initialize the three axis:
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twinx()

# data ratio for the two left y-axis:
y3_to_y1 = 1/7.5

# y-axis limits:
YLIM = [0.0, 150.0,
        0.0, 150.0]

# set up dummy data
x = np.linspace(0,70.0,70.0)
y1 = np.asarray([xi**2.0*0.032653 for xi in x])
y2 = np.asarray([xi**2.0*0.02857 for xi in x])

# plot the data
ax1.plot(x,y1,'b')
ax2.plot(x,y2,'r')

# define the axis limits
ax1.set_xlim(0.0,70.0)
ax1.set_ylim(YLIM[0],YLIM[1])
ax2.set_ylim(YLIM[2],YLIM[3])

# when specifying the limits for the left-most y-axis
# you utilize the conversion factor:
ax3.set_ylim(YLIM[2]*y3_to_y1,YLIM[3]*y3_to_y1)

# move the 3rd y-axis to the left (0.0):
ax3.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 0.0))

# set y-ticks, use np.arange for defined deltas
# add a small increment to the last ylim value
# to ensure that the last value will be a tick
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(YLIM[0],YLIM[1]+0.001,10.0))
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(YLIM[2],YLIM[3]+0.001,10.0))
ax3.set_yticks(np.arange(YLIM[2]*y3_to_y1,YLIM[3]*y3_to_y1+0.001, 2.0))

# for both letf-hand y-axis move the ticks to the outside:
ax1.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out')
ax3.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out')

plt.show()
```

This results in this figure:

[image: second figure]

Again, the `set_tick_params(direction='out')` does not work with the `axisartist` from the first example.
Somewhat counter-intuitive, both the `y1` and `y3` ticks have to be set to `'out'`. For `y1`, this makes sense, and for `y3` you have to remember that it started as a right-hand-side axis. Therefore, those ticks would appear outside (with the default `'in'` setting) when the axis is moved to the left.