# How to add a second scale to a heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

This way I created my `heatmap`:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8.27, 13.69), dpi = 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize = (8.27, 13.69))
fig = plt.gcf()

heatplot = ax.imshow(c, cmap='rainbow', aspect='auto',\
                         norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0.90))
```

`c` is the array with the `heatmap` values, normalised to one.

With `ax.set_xticklabels()`, `ax.set_xticks()`, `ax.set_yticklabels()` and `ax.set_yticks()`, I've added the axis to its `heatmap`. Now I would like to add a second `y`-axis. The orientation of the `colorbar` is horizontal.

**EDIT:**

With the Help of Bazingaa i´ve got a second y-axis, but there is an offset:

[image]

`ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(TITLES)), minor=False)` centers the ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a second `y` axis, you have to use:

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
```

where `ax1` is the current/first axis. In your case `ax1` is `ax`. Then if you plot data using `ax2`, the y-values will be displayed on the right hand side `y` axis. More info [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html)

Comment: Oh I understand now what you mean. To make both the `y` axis have the same scale, you can use `ax.set_ylim(a, b)` and `ax2.set_ylim(a, b)` where `a` and `b` are the minimum and maximum `y` value you want to see on the `y` scales. Here I assume that your axes are named `ax` and `ax1`. Modify accordingly if you have other names like `ax1` and `ax2`

Comment: No, no, i have the same limits, but there is an offset between left an right. :-/

Comment: I think I have to study this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159495/multiple-y-axis-conversion-scales

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what you are facing. Did you try doing `ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(TITLES)), minor=False)` and `ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(TITLES)), minor=False)`. I mean exact same range for both the axes? Do you still get the same problem?

Comment: Yeah, they got the same range, but there is still an "offset" between the grids. :-/

Comment: Oh try the method in the link you shared then.

Comment: Last answer of this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752464/how-do-i-align-gridlines-for-two-y-axis-scales-using-matplotlib/29542999 solved mit problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the **EDITED PART** of my question this way:

```
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim()) <-- This solvs the "Offset" between both scales

ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(len(ELEMENT[1])), minor=False)
ax2.set_yticklabels(ELEMENT[1])
```

[image]

**Where did i find it?:** [How do I align gridlines for two y-axis scales using Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752464/how-do-i-align-gridlines-for-two-y-axis-scales-using-matplotlib/29542999)

Answered by: `Hugo Alain Oliva`