# How to plot more than one variable on the same axis, on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting delay vs lambda for example. And lambda is proportional to some u like lambda = k * u where k is constant. I am plotting lambda on x-axis right now and delay on y-axis. I want to plot lambda as well as u on the x-axis as they are already proportional.

Maybe something like this:

[image: Kind of graph needed]

Please tell if this is possible. If yes, then how? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added picture.

Comment: It would help if could show a picture of what you desire. Also, what exactly is the problem of achieving such plot? Do you want two different axes, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514315/how-to-add-a-second-x-axis-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Check the edit.

Comment: See especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45925049/4124317) to the duplicate.