# Matplotlib graph with more than 2 Y axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

I'm fairly new to matplotlib and can't seem to find an answer to this: I'd like to plot 3 different graphs in one figure, all with different scales, which I'd like to align on one side like so:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbC9J.jpg)

There are a bunch of tutorials with how to do 2 axes using twinx(), but that doesn't seem to work for more than 2 axes. This (https://plot.ly/python/multiple-axes/) is almost what I want to do, only if possible I'd like to do it in native matplotlib.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Something like this? https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html

Comment: Have a look especially at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45925049/4124317), since the others are more complicated.

Answer (score 7):

I guess the following might work for you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)


fig, host = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()

# Offset the right spine of par2.  The ticks and label have already been
# placed on the right by twinx above.
par2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
# Having been created by twinx, par2 has its frame off, so the line of its
# detached spine is invisible.  First, activate the frame but make the patch
# and spines invisible.
make_patch_spines_invisible(par2)
# Second, show the right spine.
par2.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], "b-", label="Density")
p2, = par1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], "r-", label="Temperature")
p3, = par2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], "g-", label="Velocity")

host.set_xlim(0, 2)
host.set_ylim(0, 2)
par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

host.set_xlabel("Distance")
host.set_ylabel("Density")
par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
par2.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
host.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
par1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), **tkw)
par2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), **tkw)
host.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

lines = [p1, p2, p3]

host.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines])

plt.show()
```

[image]

[Source](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html)