# python - can I create another y axis next to the existing y-axis on the graph with separate values

Tags: python, matplotlib

these are my codes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
y = np.random.randint(-100,10,10)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I want to show another y-axis next to the existing one where the values will be 3 times the value on the current y-axis. i.e. the additional y-axis line will show range from -300 to -60. is it possible to do that?
[image]

Comment: [multiple axis in matplotlib with different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9103166/7758804)