# Python (Matplotlib) - show multiple figures (plots) with an x and/or y offset (so without overlapping)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I'm trying to show multiple figures at once, but with an offset so I don't have to move the first figure to check that it showed all the figures (plots).

So here's an example:

```
from pylab import *

figure(0)
plot()

figure(1)
plot()

show()
```

These figures are shown on top of each other, but I want them to look like this when I run my program:

EDIT:
[image: printcreen]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this with [`Figure.add_subplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot):

```
fig = figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.plot(...)
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax.plot(...)
show()
```

If you're wondering what the magic `211` and `212` mean, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3584805/748858).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although my question might have been unclear, I was looking for another kind of solution, I added an example in my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the tkagg backend, you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(5):
   fig = plt.figure()
   fig.canvas._tkcanvas.master.geometry('800x600+{:d}+{:d}'.format(70*i,70*i))

plt.show()
```

I think that the same treatment could be used for others backends...

Regards