# Python Pyplot: How to scale x-axis independant from number of list-elements?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale, axis

Just want to plot a list with 50 (actually 51) elements: The list indices from 0 to 50 should represent meters from 0 to 10 meters on the x-axis, while the index of every further element increases by 0.2 meters. 
Example:

```
list = [2.5, 3, 1.5, ... , 7, 9]
len(list)
>>50
```

I would like the x-axis plotted from 0 to 10 meters, i.e. 
(x,y)==(0, 2.5), (0.2, 3), (0.4, 1.5), ..., (9.8, 7), (10, 9)

Instead, the list is obviously plotted on an x-scale from 0 to 50.
Any idea how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [times series plot with pyplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743643/times-series-plot-with-pyplot)

Comment: In the future, please show the code you are using to generate the graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would avoid naming a list object `list`. It confuses the namespace. But try something like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
y = [2.5, 3, 1.5, ... , 7, 9]
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

It creates a list of point on the x-axis, which occur at multiples of `0.2` using `np.arange`, at which matplotlib will plot the y values. Numpy is a library for easily creating and manipulating vectors, matrices, and arrays, especially when they are very large.

Edit:

`fig.add_subplot(N_row,N_col,plot_number)` is the object oriented approach to plotting with matplotlib. It's useful if you want to add multiple subplots to the same figure. For example,

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
```

adds two subplots to the same figure `fig`. They will be arranged one above the other in two rows. `ax2` is the bottom subplot. Check out this [relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/in-matplotlib-what-does-111-means-in-fig-add-subplot111) for more info.

To change the actual x ticks and tick labels, use something like

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 0.5))
ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)) 
# This second line is kind of redundant but it's useful if you want 
# to format the ticks different than just plain floats.
```

Comment: Sorry for responding late and thanks, it works perfectly!
2 questions remain:
- google add_subplot(), but didn't really get, what it's good for. Any short explanation?
- How can I adjust the scale labels to get them finer? Per default, the x-axis labels are 0,2,4,6,8,10. It would be nice to have them like 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, ... while the real numbers are depicted slightly smaller.
Txh again for your help!