# How to plot multiple dataframes in subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have a few Pandas DataFrames sharing the same value scale, but having different columns and indices. When invoking `df.plot()`, I get separate plot images. what I really want is to have them all in the same plot as subplots, but I'm unfortunately failing to come up with a solution to how and would highly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

You can manually create the subplots with matplotlib, and then plot the dataframes on a specific subplot using the `ax` keyword. For example for 4 subplots (2x2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

df1.plot(ax=axes[0,0])
df2.plot(ax=axes[0,1])
...
```

Here `axes` is an array which holds the different subplot axes, and you can access one just by indexing `axes`.
If you want a shared x-axis, then you can provide `sharex=True` to `plt.subplots`.

Answer (score 139):

You can see e.gs. in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/visualization.html#targeting-different-subplots) demonstrating joris answer. Also from the documentation, you could also set `subplots=True` and `layout=(,)` within the pandas `plot` function:

```
df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(1,2))
```

You could also use `fig.add_subplot()` which takes subplot grid parameters such as 221, 222, 223, 224, etc. as described in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/in-matplotlib-what-does-111-mean-in-fig-add-subplot111). Nice examples of plot on pandas data frame, including subplots, can be seen in [this ipython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/fonnesbeck/5850463/raw/a29d9ffb863bfab09ff6c1fc853e1d5bf69fe3e4/3.+Plotting+and+Visualization.ipynb).

Comment: although joris' answer is great for general matplotlib usage this is excellent for anyone wanting to using pandas for quick data visualisation. It also fits inline with the question a bit better.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `subplots` and `layout` kwargs will generate multiple plots ONLY for a single dataframe. This is related to, but not a solution for OP's question of plotting multiple dataframes into a single plot.

Comment: This is the better answer for pure Pandas use. This doesn't require importing matplotlib directly (though you normally should anyways) and doesn't require looping for arbitrary shapes (can use `layout=(df.shape[1], 1)`, for example).

Answer (score 48):

You can plot multiple subplots of multiple pandas data frames using matplotlib with a simple trick of making a list of all data frame. Then using the for loop for plotting subplots.

***Working code:***

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# dataframe sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*100, columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*100, columns=['A', 'B'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*100, columns=['A', 'B'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*100, columns=['A', 'B'])
df5 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*100, columns=['A', 'B'])
df6 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2)*100, columns=['A', 'B'])

#define number of rows and columns for subplots
nrow=3
ncol=2

# make a list of all dataframes 
df_list = [df1 ,df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol)

# plot counter
count=0
for r in range(nrow):
    for c in range(ncol):
        df_list[count].plot(ax=axes[r,c])
        count+=1
```

[image]

Using this code you can plot subplots in any configuration.  You need to define the number of rows `nrow` and the number of columns `ncol`. Also, you need to make list of data frames `df_list` which you wanted to plot.

Comment: What are your settings that produce gridlines instead of ticks? When I use my default pandas 1.3.5 with matplotlib 3.5.3 the plot looks differently, with clear white background and ticks on the outside of the axes.

Answer (score 37):

You can use the familiar Matplotlib style calling a `figure` and `subplot`, but you simply need to specify the current axis using `plt.gca()`. An example:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
df.A.plot() #no need to specify for first axis
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
df.B.plot(ax=plt.gca())
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
df.C.plot(ax=plt.gca())
```

etc...

Comment: I think it is fine to use `ax=plt.gca()` on the first plot as well.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(221)
plt.plot(x,y)

ax = fig.add_subplot(222)
plt.plot(x,z)
...

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

You may not need to use Pandas at all. Here's a matplotlib plot of cat frequencies:

[image]

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x**2)

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
for c, i in enumerate(axes):
  axes[c].plot(x, y)
  axes[c].set_title('cats')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 4):

### Option 1: Create subplots from a dictionary of dataframes with long (tidy) data

- Assumptions:

  - There is a dictionary of multiple dataframes of tidy data that are either:

    - Created by reading in from files
    - Created by separating a single dataframe into multiple dataframes
  - The categories, `cat`, may be overlapping, but all dataframes don't necessarily contain all values of `cat`
  - `hue='cat'`
- This example uses a `dict` of dataframes, but a `list` of dataframes would be similar.
- If the dataframes are wide, use [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to convert them to long form.
- Because dataframes are being iterated through, there's no guarantee that colors will be mapped the same for each plot

  - A custom color map needs to be created from the unique `'cat'` values for all the dataframes
  - Since the colors will be the same, place one legend to the side of the plots, instead of a legend in every plot
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

#### Imports and Test Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # used for random data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch  # for custom legend - square patches
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D  # for custom legend - round markers
import seaborn as sns
import math import ceil  # determine correct number of subplot

# synthetic data
df_dict = dict()
for i in range(1, 7):
    np.random.seed(i)  # for repeatable sample data
    data_length = 100
    data = {'cat': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=data_length),
            'x': np.random.rand(data_length), 'y': np.random.rand(data_length)}
    df_dict[i] = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df_dict[1].head())
  cat         x         y
0   B  0.944595  0.606329
1   A  0.586555  0.568851
2   A  0.903402  0.317362
3   B  0.137475  0.988616
4   B  0.139276  0.579745

# display(df_dict[6].tail())
   cat         x         y
95   B  0.881222  0.263168
96   A  0.193668  0.636758
97   A  0.824001  0.638832
98   C  0.323998  0.505060
99   C  0.693124  0.737582
```

#### Create color mappings and plot

```py
# create color mapping based on all unique values of cat
unique_cat = {cat for v in df_dict.values() for cat in v.cat.unique()}  # get unique cats
colors = sns.color_palette('tab10', n_colors=len(unique_cat))  # get a number of colors
cmap = dict(zip(unique_cat, colors))  # zip values to colors

col_nums = 3  # how many plots per row
row_nums = math.ceil(len(df_dict) / col_nums)  # how many rows of plots

# create the figure and axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(row_nums, col_nums, figsize=(9, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True, tight_layout=True)
# convert to 1D array for easy iteration
axes = axes.flat

# iterate through dictionary and plot
for ax, (k, v) in zip(axes, df_dict.items()):
    
    sns.scatterplot(data=v, x='x', y='y', hue='cat', palette=cmap, ax=ax)
    sns.despine(top=True, right=True)
    ax.legend_.remove()  # remove the individual plot legends
    ax.set_title(f'dataset = {k}', fontsize=11)

# create legend from cmap
# patches = [Patch(color=v, label=k) for k, v in cmap.items()]  # square patches
patches = [Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', markerfacecolor=v, label=k, markersize=8) for k, v in cmap.items()]  # round markers

# place legend outside of plot; change the right bbox value to move the legend up or down
plt.legend(title='cat', handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.06, 1.2), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0, frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Option 2: Create subplots from a single dataframe with multiple separate datasets

- The dataframes must be in a long form with the same column names.
- This option uses [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine multiple dataframes into a single dataframe, and [`.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add a new column.

  - See [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804) for creating a single dataframes from a list of files.
- This option is easier because it doesn't require manually mapping colors to `'cat'`

##### Combine DataFrames

```py
# using df_dict, with dataframes as values, from the top
# combine all the dataframes in df_dict to a single dataframe with an identifier column
df = pd.concat((v.assign(dataset=k) for k, v in df_dict.items()), ignore_index=True)

# display(df.head())
  cat         x         y  dataset
0   B  0.944595  0.606329        1
1   A  0.586555  0.568851        1
2   A  0.903402  0.317362        1
3   B  0.137475  0.988616        1
4   B  0.139276  0.579745        1

# display(df.tail())
    cat         x         y  dataset
595   B  0.881222  0.263168        6
596   A  0.193668  0.636758        6
597   A  0.824001  0.638832        6
598   C  0.323998  0.505060        6
599   C  0.693124  0.737582        6
```

##### Plot a FacetGrid with [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot)

```py
g = sns.relplot(kind='scatter', data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='cat', col='dataset', col_wrap=3, height=3)
```

[image]

---

- Both options create the same result, however, it's less complicated to combine all the dataframes, and plot a [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) plot with `sns.relplot`.

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
imoprt matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(1,100,10), 
                   'B': np.random.randint(100,1000,10),
                   'C':np.random.randint(100,200,10)})
for ax in ax.flatten():
    df.plot(ax =ax)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked in the OP. The question is how to plot **multiple** dataframes in subplots; while this answer plots the same dataframe multiple times. Additionally, `.flat` (the same as `.flatten`) is already shown, so that’s nothing new. The point of SO is to answer the question that was asked. Additionally, there are other SO questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793513/7758804) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68323343/7758804)) that already deal with the question of single dataframes with subplots.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @joris response above, if you have already established a reference to the subplot, you can use the reference as well. For example,

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((50,100), (0, 0), colspan=20, rowspan=10)
...

df.plot.barh(ax=ax1, stacked=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working pandas subplot example, where modes is the column names of the dataframe.

```
    dpi=200
    figure_size=(20, 10)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(modes), 1, sharex="all", sharey="all", dpi=dpi)
    for i in range(len(modes)):
        ax[i] = pivot_df.loc[:, modes[i]].plot.bar(figsize=(figure_size[0], figure_size[1]*len(modes)),
                                                   ax=ax[i], title=modes[i], color=my_colors[i])
        ax[i].legend()
    fig.suptitle(name)
```

[image: Pandas subplot bar example]