# How to plot column from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to plot integer columns of dataframe. I am trying by following way

```
for i in df:
    if df[i].dtypes == 'int64':
        df[i].plot.kde()
```

But it is plotting all in the same graph. I am new to it and would like to know how can I do it?

Comment: This answer may help your question :[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-can-i-plot-separate-pandas-dataframes-as-subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-can-i-plot-separate-pandas-dataframes-as-subplots)  `df.select_dtypes(include=["integer"]).columns.size` calculates your axis size.

Comment: DO you want one graph per time, subplots?..

Comment: I would like to have distribution of each column data in one figure

Comment: Again, we don't know what df contains and what your desired output is. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You probably simply have to add a "plt.legend()
plt.show()" after the loop to get your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add plot option in your loop:

```
for i in df: 
    if df[i].dtypes == 'int64': 
        df[i].plot.kde()
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need :

```
df[(df.dtypes == 'int64').index].plot.kde(subplots=True)
#we find the columns that have int64 values and plot all columns in different plot
```

Using your code :
[image: all plots together]
using above code
[image: all plots together]