# Boxplot subplot not showing due to NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an issue when plotting a boxplot in a subplot. My data is a time series with `datetime index` which contains `NaNs`. This is the code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5, 3))
ax.boxplot([df['col1'], df['col2']])
plt.show()
```

It shows and empty graph (Figue (a) below) and `'RuntimeWarning: Invalid value encountered in percentile interpolation=interpolation`.' When `NaNs` are removed, the plot is showing, but I don't want to remove `NaNs` before boxplotting because the result is different.
[image]

When using the following code, it returns the **correct** plot (Figure (b)), but not in a **subplot**.

```
df.boxplot(column=['col1', 'col2'], figsize=(5, 3))
```

I want something like Figure (b) in a subplot.

Comment: Can you put the whole code?

Comment: @Petronella Those are the whole code, except that the resulted graphs are individual instead of in one figure.

Comment: maybe try `df.plot(kind='box', subplots=True)` ?

Comment: @Chris A. Thanks, i can implement it to get a plot where one graph represents a column. Don't know yet how to make the plot more customizable, such as: two boxplots in one graph, a different color for each graph, etc. Using ```fig, ax = plt.subplots(........)``` then ```ax.boxplot(......)``` seems to have more freedom to me.

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-can-i-plot-separate-pandas-dataframes-as-subplots

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly said, the problem could be due to NANs in the columns. If you don't want to remove NANs, replace them with a '0' or an appropriate value you think.

The below shall work.

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I don't think nan should be replaced with 0 since this will impact box plot. Nan values either be dropped or ignored from data frame.