# How to create subplot from various data frames

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a list of data frames:

```
list_df = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
```

of which are are defined by fairly identical commands:

```
df6 = df_2016['Incident Type Description'].value_counts()[:20]
```

Where  `df1 = df_2011['Incident Type Description'].value_counts()[:20]`,
`df2 = df_2012['Incident Type Description'].value_counts()[:20]` and so on to `df6 = df_2016['Incident Type Description'].value_counts()[:20]`. `df_2011, df_2012...df_2016` are named variables from csv files I uploaded.

What I wish to do is join all these to create a 2x3 subplot instead of having them individually displayed of which I had with the command: `df_2016['Incident Type Description'].value_counts()[:20].plot(kind='barh', title='Top 20 crimes in Oakland in 2016')`

I have tried a few approaches so far that I have found on stackoverflow [[How can I plot separate Pandas DataFrames as subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-can-i-plot-separate-pandas-dataframes-as-subplots]) and the matplotlib page, but these do not work and I don't know why (I'm a beginner in python):

```
axes= plt.subplots(2, 3)
list_df = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]

columns = [f'Top 20 crimes in {x}' for x in range(2011, 2017)]

list_df.plot.barh(subplots=True, layout=(2, 3), figsize=(15,7))
```

So far `ValueError` comes up as `ValueError: Layout of 2x3 must be larger than required size 7`. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is `df` that you are plotting? Aren't you trying to plot `df1,df2,...`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes that's supposed to be list_df, sorry only just realised I left that out. Now `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'plot'`. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,3)

for d, ax in zip(list_df, axes.ravel()):
    d.plot.barh(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you planned to use another package. But Seaborn is quite often used to display nicely and quickly different kinds of plots. You can check the complete package doc : [Seaborn Doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html). There are some nice tutorials.

Especially FacetGrid to display suplots. [FacetGrid Doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html#grid-tutorial)

Seaborn is built on top of matplot lib.

Edit : You could maybe need to append all you df, and then subplot based on a column specifying the input df(1-6).