# How would I vectorize a function in pandas that returns a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, vectorization

I've been reading about [how to optimize pandas code for speed](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6), and I'm trying to refactor my code, changing from `iterrows()` to vectorization. Here is an example of the old code and its result:

**Old Code**

```
import pandas as pd
def repeatAsList(value):
    return([value, value])
df = pd.DataFrame({"values": [1,2,3], "repeatedAsList":None})
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[index,"repeatedAsList"] = repeatAsList(row['values'])
df
```

**Old Result**

```
+--------+----------------+
| values | repeatedAsList |
+--------+----------------+
|      1 | [1, 1]         |
|      2 | [2, 2]         |
|      3 | [3, 3]         |
+--------+----------------+
```

**New Code**

```
import pandas as pd
def repeatAsList(value):
    return([value, value])
df = pd.DataFrame({"values": [1,2,3], "repeatedAsList":None})
df["repeatedAsList"] = repeatAsList(df["values"])
```

**New Result**

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I'd like to understand why the new code above fails, and if it's possible to run a different way and achieve speed improvements from the old code. I feel like I'm missing a key point of vectorization, and it would be nice to learn why the values have to be scalar.

Comment: If you are going to have `list `objects inside your data-frame, you are essentially removing any change for performance improvements due to vectorization, because it necessitates an object dtype

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it faster by creating an array using the values:

```
df['repeatedAsList'] = [[x,x] for x in (df['values'].values)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  values repeatedAsList
0       1         [1, 1]
1       2         [2, 2]
2       3         [3, 3]
```

#### Regarding speed:

Here you can see the speed for larger dataframes and accesing them with `values`, `tolist()` and some other functions. I believe the fastest way to access the values is `.values` for larger datasets (100+ rows): [getting value error when tried to make subplots for list of dataframe with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119575/getting-value-error-when-tried-to-make-subplots-for-list-of-dataframe-with-matpl/60119635#60119635)

```
                        1      10     100    1000   10000
len 1               0.0038  0.0046  0.0032  0.0037  0.0035
len 10              0.0032  0.0032  0.0032  0.0034  0.0035
len 100             0.0032  0.0052  0.0052  0.0053  0.0035
len 1000            0.0037  0.0036  0.0041  0.0039  0.0043
len 10000           0.0040  0.0038  0.0045  0.0043  0.0123
len(tolist) 1       0.0051  0.0075  0.0175  0.1629  1.6579
len(tolist) 10      0.0051  0.0059  0.0175  0.1588  1.9253
len(tolist) 100     0.0049  0.0097  0.0196  0.1635  1.7422
len(tolist) 1000    0.0053  0.0065  0.0198  0.1831  1.9897
len(tolist) 10000   0.0057  0.0069  0.0218  0.1995  2.2426
len(values) 1       0.0083  0.0097  0.0073  0.0074  0.0074
len(values) 10      0.0073  0.0072  0.0073  0.0107  0.0087
len(values) 100     0.0075  0.0094  0.0109  0.0072  0.0081
len(values) 1000    0.0081  0.0082  0.0081  0.0085  0.0088
len(values) 10000   0.0087  0.0084  0.0103  0.0101  0.0327
shape   1           0.1108  0.0838  0.0789  0.0779  0.0780
shape   10          0.0764  0.0770  0.0771  0.1118  0.0806
shape   100         0.0952  0.0826  0.1013  0.0800  0.0889
shape   1000        0.0881  0.0863  0.0867  0.0938  0.1063
shape   10000       0.0905  0.0999  0.1043  0.1013  0.2384
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly the below code should be able to complete your requested task easily :

```
df['repeated_column'] = [[item, item] for item in df['values'].to_list()]
```

Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `map`:

```
df['repeatedAsList'] = list(map(lambda x: [x,x], df['values'].values))
#df['repeatedAsList'] = list(map(lambda x: [x,x], df['values']) #seems slow


   values repeatedAsList 
0       1         [1, 1] 
1       2         [2, 2] 
2       3         [3, 3]
```

Comment: List and lambda and map are really slow, let alone a combination. However it is indeed a valid approach