# Two subplots side by side with groupby method

Tags: matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I am trying to put 2 matplotlib figures side by side but each resulted from a groupby function (see code below, only show the second plot). I am aware that similar questions have been asked before but none are exactly like this one. I appreciate any help.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRACu.png)

```
ax = df_train.groupby(['Role','Side'])['Result'].mean().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(5,6), fontsize=13)
ax.set_ylabel('Win Rate')
ax.set_title('Win Rate by Role and Side')


ax1 = df_train.groupby(['Role','Side'])['Result'].count().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(5,6), fontsize=13)
ax1.set_ylabel('# of games')
ax1.set_title('# of games by Role and Side')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I plot separate Pandas DataFrames as subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-can-i-plot-separate-pandas-dataframes-as-subplots)

Comment: I found that link in my first search but it unfortunately doesn't work with the codes. The error is `'Series' object has no attribute 'subplots'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-can-i-plot-separate-pandas-dataframes-as-subplots), this is what you need to do:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,6))
df_train.groupby(['Role','Side'])['Result'].mean().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1, fontsize=13)
ax1.set_ylabel('Win Rate')
ax1.set_title('Win Rate by Role and Side')

df_train.groupby(['Role','Side'])['Result'].count().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, fontsize=13)
ax2.set_ylabel('# of games')
ax2.set_title('# of games by Role and Side')
```

plt.show()

Comment: Thank you for being patient! Sorry I needed some hand-holding there. This works great!