# Plotting Pandas Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Suppose I have the following Pandas df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( data = {'Day': ['2020-08-30', '2020-08-30','2020-08-30','2020-08-30',
                                        '2020-08-29', '2020-08-29','2020-08-29','2020-08-29',
                                            '2020-08-28', '2020-08-28','2020-08-28','2020-08-28'],
                                'Curve': ['Brazil', 'Japan','Brazil', 'Japan','Brazil', 'Japan','Brazil', 'Japan','Brazil', 'Japan','Brazil', 'Japan'],
                                'Value': [100, 950, 200, 1000, 50, 50, 250, 1200, 20, 30, 240, 1100],
                                'Expiry': ['1Y', '1Y', '2Y','2Y','1Y','1Y','2Y','2Y', '1Y','1Y','2Y','2Y']})

df['Difference'] = df.groupby(['Curve', 'Expiry']).Value.diff(-1)
```

[Example Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl6b9.png)

I would like to plot it and have it result in the following graph, would anyone know how to do that? Basically, to plot the "difference" by "Curve", where the X axis is the "Expiry". I don't care about the legends, axis-name, etc. Just to understand how to plot the curves by expiry.

Desired Pyplot graph

[image: Desired Pyplot graph]

Also interested if its possible to know how to plot the curves in two separate graphs (i.e, one graph for each separate curve). Thanks in advance and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a pivot operation. But first it seems you want to filter only the last date.

```
df2 = (
    df[df.Day=='2020-08-30']
    .pivot(index='Expiry', columns='Curve', values='Difference')
)
print(df2)

df2.plot()
plt.show()
```

Output

```
Curve   Brazil  Japan
Expiry
1Y        50.0  900.0
2Y       -50.0 -200.0
```

[image]

---

Update

You can get the last date with `df.Day.max()` and you can select lines you want to plot with `df.filter`.

```
df.sort_values('Day', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df2 = (
    df[df.Day==df.Day.max()]
    .pivot(index='Expiry', columns='Curve', values='Difference')
)

only_columns = ['Brazil', 'North Korea']
df2 = df2.filter(items=only_columns, axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Output

```
Curve   Brazil
Expiry
1Y        50.0
2Y       -50.0
```

Comment: Thanks Richie, your answer is helpful.  Only if you want (you already helped a lot), do you know how would it go to plot different graphs for each separate "Curve"?

Comment: @Pepini2341 see the second answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/22483588/6692898

Comment: @Pepini2341 I don't think anyone here would mind helping with a little clarification like that, but it is good getting used to searching around... I like googling "stackoverflow.com my query" to get better results... then if you still don't find the right answer by all means, comment or ask a new question... most likely it is just a matter of one not finding the right words to phrase our question

Answer (score 0):

hi you get the desired result like this

```
df2=df[["Difference","Day","Curve"]]
braz=df2[df2['Curve']=='Brazil']
jap=df2[df2['Curve']=='Japan']

braz=df2[df2['Curve']=='Brazil']
jap=df2[df2['Curve']=='Japan']


f, axes  = plt.subplots(1)

axes.plot(list(range(braz.shape[0])),braz["Difference"],label="Brazil")
axes.plot(list(range(braz.shape[0])),jap["Difference"],label="Japan")

axes.legend()
axes.set_xlabel('Difference')
axes.set_ylabel('?')


f.set_figheight(8)
f.set_figwidth(8)
```

Comment: The x-axis should be Expiry