# How to plot multiple dataframes in a single catplot figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, catplot

I have multiple data frames consist of three main columns: 1)the categories (c1, c2, c3), one includes the data values, and one includes different time-periods (AA, BB, CC, DD).

what I am trying to generate is to generate boxplots of the data for all dataframe, at once, and in one figure !
I did try with different enumerate options and "ax" argument, but still it generates the boxplot separately, I couldn't figure it out.

```
allCN=[df1, df2, df3]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols=4, figsize = (30,54))
axes = axes.flatten()

for i, x in enumerate(allCN):

    sns.set(style="ticks", palette='Set2')
    sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.1, rc={"lines.linewidth": 1.1})

    g=sns.catplot(x="Cat", y="Data", ax=axs[i,0],
                   col="Period", data=x, kind="box", height=4, aspect=10/18,
                     width=0.6,fliersize=2.5,showfliers=False, linewidth=1.1,
                     notch=False,orient="v"))
    g.set_ylabels("test", size=12)
    g.set_xlabels("")
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Similar to [How to plot multiple dataframes in subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22483588/7758804)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to stack your data frames and use the `row=` argument inside `catplot`. First to create something like your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Cat':np.random.choice(['C1','C2','C3'],50),
                    'Data':np.random.uniform(0,1,50),"Period":np.random.choice(['AA','CC','DD'],50)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Cat':np.random.choice(['C1','C2','C3'],50),
                    'Data':np.random.uniform(0,1,50),"Period":np.random.choice(['AA','CC','DD'],50)})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Cat':np.random.choice(['C1','C2','C3'],50),
                    'Data':np.random.uniform(0,1,50),"Period":np.random.choice(['AA','CC','DD'],50)})
```

Then concat the dataframes and add another column (i used source below) to annotate the dataframe:

```
allCN=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
allCN['source'] = np.repeat(['df1','df2','df3'],[len(df1),len(df2),len(df3)])

sns.catplot(x="Cat", y="Data",
            col="Period", row = "source", 
            data=allCN, kind="box", height=2,aspect=1.6)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works! is there anyway to reduce the 'h space or w space' like the Mathplotlib?

Comment: `allCN['source'] = np.repeat(['df1','df2','df3'],[len(df1),len(df2),len(df3)])` is so much nicer than iterating through the dataframe to add a new column, and then doing `pd.concat`. It deserves more upvotes.

Comment: Even better `df = pd.concat((df.assign(source=f'df{i}') for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3])))` using `.assign`, which I found as a comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804)

Answer (score 2):

What about the hue parameter in [sns.boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)? Would that give you the result you want?

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
box_plot = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, hue="smoker")
plt.show()
```