# Plot separate pandas dataframe as subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot pandas dataframes as subplots.

I read this post: [How can I plot separate Pandas DataFrames as subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-can-i-plot-separate-pandas-dataframes-as-subplots)

Here is my minimum example where, like the accepted answer in the post, I used the `ax` keyword:

```
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, subplots

import numpy as np  

# Definition of the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({'Pressure': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4}, 'Volume': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 8}, 'Temperature': {0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 12}})


# Plot
 
fig,axes = subplots(2,1)

df.plot(x='Temperature', y=['Volume'], marker = 'o',ax=axes[0,0])

df.plot(x='Temperature', y=['Pressure'], marker = 'o',ax=axes[1,0])


show()
```

Unfortunately, there is a problem with the indices:

```
df.plot(x='Temperature', y=['Volume'], marker = 'o',ax=axes[0,0])

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Please, could you help me ?

Comment: `ax=axes[0]` and `ax=axes[1]`

Comment: It is solved. Thank you for your quick answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one dimension (like 2 x 1 subplots), you can just used axes[0] and axes[1]. When you have two dimensional subplots (2 x 3 subplots for example), you indeed need slicing with two numbers.