# Subplots with specific Columns from Single Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am so close..
I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
      date    gpa   use   dev
  20210614  52.50  2.30  2.49
  20210616  52.43  2.28  2.47
  20210623  53.41  2.41  2.57
  20210630  55.98  2.33  2.58
```

I can plot a single line chart to file with:

```
outpath = "/tmp/"
df.plot(x='date',y='gpa',kind='line').get_figure().savefig(outpath)
```

However, I would like to draw a subplot, with each column: gpa, use, dev against my date column.

I also tried this, which plots a single chart to file with all 3 series on the same x-y:

```
df.plot(x='date')
plt.subplot().getfigure().savefig(outpath)
```

As you can see from the source data, use and dev columns are much smaller scale.
How can I go about plotting each on their own y-axis e.g. 3x smaller charts on the same output?

I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `subplots=True` to [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and do not specify a `y` value:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [20210614, 20210616, 20210623, 20210630],
    'gpa': [52.5, 52.43, 53.41, 55.98],
    'use': [2.3, 2.28, 2.41, 2.33],
    'dev': [2.49, 2.47, 2.57, 2.58]
})

df.plot(x='date', kind='line', subplots=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1 int xaxis]

---

Optional convert `date` [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for clearer `x-axis` ticks:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df.plot(x='date', kind='line', subplots=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2 datetime xaxis]