# Matlplotlib and four plots in same picture

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with matplotlib and I want to make four subplots in the same picture. Below you can see example of my data and my desired plot.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    pd.set_option('max_columns', None)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data = {
                     'type_sale': ['group_1','group_2','group_3','group_4','group_5','group_6','group_7','group_8','group_9','group_10'],
                     'open':[70,20,24,80,20,20,60,20,20,20],
                     'closed':[30,14,20,10,10,40,10,10,10,10],
                    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['type_sale',
                                               'open',
                                               'closed',
                                               ])
# Barplot with matplotlib    
            
df.plot(x='type_sale', kind='bar', stacked=True,
                    title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')
```

[image]

Now I want to replicate this barplot four times in the same picture with the subplot command and save it in pdf. I tried this with the lines of codes below :

```
# Setup the subplot2grid Layout
fig = plt.figure()
# Plot 1
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,0))
ax1.df.plot(x='type_sale', kind='bar', stacked=True,
        title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')

# Plot 2
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1,0))
ax2.df.plot(x='type_sale', kind='bar', stacked=True,
        title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')

# Plot 3
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,1))
ax3.df.plot(x='type_sale', kind='bar', stacked=True,
        title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')


# Plot 4
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1,1))
ax4.df.plot(x='type_sale', kind='bar', stacked=True,
        title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('fig_name.pdf') 
plt.show()
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the goal to create 4 graphs with the same data? If the data for each graph is different, how are they different?

Comment: This is only an example. Of course, I plan to plot four different charts. For simplicity and for an easy understanding of this problem I put same graph

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I plot separate Pandas DataFrames as subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-can-i-plot-separate-pandas-dataframes-as-subplots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way, I think the example in the official [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#using-layout-and-targeting-multiple-axes), is to assign the graph of pandas to it as `axs` creates a graph for each of the subplots. For a summary title, use `plt.suptitle`. If you need individual titles, specify a title for each, as in the reference example.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(8,6))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2, hspace=0.6)
df.plot(x='type_sale', kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=axs[0,0])
df.plot(x='type_sale', kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=axs[0,1])
df.plot(x='type_sale', kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=axs[1,0])
df.plot(x='type_sale', kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=axs[1,1])

plt.suptitle(t='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]