# how can i plot multiple graph into one with matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

This is what my dataframe looks like: click on the line to download dataframe

[enter link description here for dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AUqojPfRY6mp-idxj6ZJhc0sAQQ20WYe/view?usp=share_link)

[image]

I have tried the following code :

```
plt.plot(LessDF['DeptAvg'][LessDF['classes'] == 'COA111'], LessDF['week1'])
plt.plot(LessDF['DeptAvg'][LessDF['classes'] == 'COA111'], LessDF['week2'])
plt.plot(LessDF['DeptAvg'][LessDF['classes'] == 'COA111'], LessDF['week3'])
```

I got the output below, which shows only one line, with my code.
[image]

I want output with separate lines, like this:
[image]

How can I get this output with matplotlib or seaborn??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot multiple dataframes in subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-to-plot-multiple-dataframes-in-subplots)

Comment: No this can't helpful to me @T C Molenaar your suggested solution is for subplot on same cell. I want multiple plot on one subplot.

Comment: You should provide an example of your data to make your issue reproducible. It is not clear what `LessDF` looks like. It might be that your lines are just overlapping. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have updated the question & now can view the dataframe also.

Comment: images aren't ideal for sharing data but thanks

Comment: thank you for providing the link to the CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Seaborn, with its [object interface](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html) available from v0.12, you might do like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

sns.set_theme()
```

First, convert the data frame into a [long-form](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) for easier processing in the second figure.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("LessDF.csv", index_col=0)

df_long = (
    # Convert to a long-form
    pd.melt(df,
        id_vars=["Id", "classes", "LessAvg", "DeptAvg"],
        var_name=["week"],
        value_name="point"
    )

    # Make `week1` to `1`
    .assign(week=lambda df_: df_.week.str.replace("week", ""))
)
```

Then

```
(
    so.Plot(
        # We don't have to drop rows but since `DeptAvg` doesn't change
        # over `classes` and `week`, we can de-duplicate them
        df_long.drop_duplicates(["classes", "week"]),
        x="week", y="DeptAvg", color="classes"
    )
    .add(so.Line())
    .limit(y=(0, 100))
)
```

[image]

If you'd like to also render the individual `Id`'s point of each week, you might do something like this:

```py
(
    so.Plot(data=df_long, x="week", y="point", color="classes")
    .add(so.Dots(), so.Dodge(), so.Jitter(.3))
    .add(so.Line(linewidth=3, alpha=.8), y="DeptAvg")
    .limit(y=(0, 100))
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the exact solution i wated @ryu 1 kn Thanks. This will helps me to solve my many of doubts.

Answer (score 1):

All your values in the DeptAvg column are 67 for the filter you applied.

Also, you are providing a boolean as your x: `LessDF['DeptAvg'] == 'COA111'`.

Also, you are applying the condition on the wrong column `DeptAvg` instead of `classes`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('../../../Desktop/LessDF.csv')
df_filtered = df[df['classes'] == 'COA111' ]

plt.plot(df_filtered['week1'],df_filtered['DeptAvg'],alpha=.5,)
plt.plot(df_filtered['week2'],df_filtered['DeptAvg'],alpha=.5)
plt.plot(df_filtered['week3'],df_filtered['DeptAvg'],alpha=.5)

plt.legend(['week1','week2','week3'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

more info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plot-multiple-plots-in-matplotlib/)

Comment: what are you talking about?
the answer is given..

Comment: My intention was not to you @Claudio Paladini

Comment: This solution is helpful to me @Claudio Paladini. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
# I done this using seaborn you can use matplotlib in between to code
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16)) 
plt.subplot(no_of_rows, no_of_columns, plot_num)
plt.title('Any title 1')
sns.boxplot(df['column_name'])

Example :- we want 2 rows with columns of plots then we use
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.title('Any title 1')
sns.distplot(df['column_name'], bins=20)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.title('Any title 2')
sns.distplot(df['column_name'], bins=20)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.title('Any title 3')
sns.distplot(df['column_name'], bins=20)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.title('Any title 4')
sns.distplot(df['column_name'], bins=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: as per the comments to the questions, he is not looking for subplots. Instead, he is looking for multiple lines in one plot.

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(16,10))

sns.boxplot(df,y="arpu_6",ax=ax[0,0])
ax[0,0].set_title("June ARPU")
ax[0,0].set_ylim([0, 5000])

sns.boxplot(df,y="arpu_7",ax=ax[0,1])
ax[0,1].set_title("July ARPU")
ax[0,1].set_ylim([0, 5000])

sns.boxplot(df,y="arpu_8",ax=ax[0,2])
ax[0,2].set_title("Aug ARPU")
ax[0,2].set_ylim([0, 5000])
```

I picked off the code from my own notebook, so doesn't match your dataframe, so just modify as per your needs.