# How to create multiple histograms on separate graphs with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, enthought, canopy

I have 5 data sets from which I want to create 5 separate histograms.  At the moment they are all going on one graph. How can I change this so that it produces two separate graphs?

For simplicity, in my example below I am showing just two histograms. I am looking at the distribution of angle `a` at 3 different times and the same for angle `b`.

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(a)
plt.xlabel('Angle a (degrees)') 
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(b)
label='2pm,3pm,4pm'
loc = 'center'
plt.legend(label, loc)

plt.xlabel('Angle b(degrees)')        
plt.title('Histogram of b')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
label='2pm,3pm,4pm'
loc = 'center'
plt.legend(label, loc)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is probably when you want to use matplotlib's [object-oriented interface](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pythonic_matplotlib.html). There are a couple ways that you could handle this.

First, you could want each plot on an entirely separate figure. In which case, matplotlib lets you keep track of various figures.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.normal(size=200)
b = np.random.normal(size=200)

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(a)
ax1.set_xlabel('Angle a (degrees)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency')

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(b)
ax2.set_xlabel('Angle b (degrees)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Frequency')
```

Or, you can divide your figure into multiple subplots and plot a histogram on each of those. In which case matplotlib lets you keep track of the various subplots.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)

n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(a)
ax1.set_xlabel('Angle a (degrees)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency')

n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(b)
ax2.set_xlabel('Angle b (degrees)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Frequency')
```

Answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/in-matplotlib-what-does-111-means-in-fig-add-subplot111) explain the numbers in `add_subplot`.

Answer (score 8):

I recently used [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) for doing the same thing. If you're reading from csv/text then it could be really easy.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv") # columns a,b,c,etc
data.hist(bins=20)
```

It's really just wrapping the matplotlib into one call, but works nicely.

Comment: This is how I used it too, but that's also why I am here. Since when you start using `data.a.hist()` and `data.b.hist()` they all go into one single chart, while I want them to be in separate charts. So the accepted answer indeed helps here while this one unfortunately not :)