# Is there a way to save networkx 'draw' result to a file or variable instead of displaying it?

Tags: networkx

I would like to generate a graph's drawing but save it to file instead of displaying it to screen. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the documentation](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/readwrite.html) you are looking for, with many solutions. I may add that if no one is supposed to read or modify the created file (it's just a storing format), you may use pickle. If you need a more generic format because the graph will be used in other tools you may prefer graphML or Json.

Example:

```
>>> cube = nx.hypercube_graph(2)
>>> nx.write_gpickle(cube,"cube.gpickle")
>>> readCube = nx.read_gpickle("cube.gpickle")
>>> cube.edge
{(0, 1): {(0, 0): {}, (1, 1): {}}, (1, 0): {(0, 0): {}, (1, 1): {}}, (0, 0): {(0, 1): {}, (1, 0): {}}, (1, 1): {(0, 1): {}, (1, 0): {}}}
>>> readCube.edge
{(0, 1): {(0, 0): {}, (1, 1): {}}, (1, 0): {(0, 0): {}, (1, 1): {}}, (0, 0): {(0, 1): {}, (1, 0): {}}, (1, 1): {(0, 1): {}, (1, 0): {}}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers OP's question. To my understanding, OP wants to save the figure of the graph, not the actual information of the graph. @alabastericestalagtite answer is probably the one that should be accepted.

Answer (score 29):

Yes! `networkx` will draw to a matplotlib figure, and you can use all `matplotlib` API thereafter, including saving the file (to chosen format and dpi).

```
import networkx
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot

g = networkx.Graph()
g.add_edge(1,2)
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
networkx.draw(g, ax=fig.add_subplot())
if True: 
    # Save plot to file
    matplotlib.use("Agg") 
    fig.savefig("graph.png")
else:
    # Display interactive viewer
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Explanatory Notes:

1. `matplotlib.use("Agg")` is optional. It is appropriate for programs that never want to show interactively viewer.
2. `f.add_subplot()` all parameters are optional:

   - ['what is the `fig.add_subplot(111)` argument' (stackoverflow.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/what-does-the-argument-mean-in-fig-add-subplot111)
   - api documentation [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html), explains first args parameter