# Matplotlib - subplots spanning multiple rows using `plt.subplots()`

Tags: python, matplotlib

Per the (many) answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/in-matplotlib-what-does-111-mean-in-fig-add-subplot111), I should try to use plt.subplots() to create figure axes when I'm not interested in an audience of `MATLAB` users. One thing that isn't clear to me (and is not shown in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) ) is how to create subplots that span multiple axes using this invocation. How to do it other ways, e.g. by repeatedly calling `add_subplot`, has been discussed elsewhere.

So, how do I use `plt.subplots()` to instantiate a figure with subplots of different sizes?

The folowing code ([source](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_tight_layout.html)) gives the behavior I'm talking about, but with different invocations.

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax2 = plt.subplot(223)
ax3 = plt.subplot(122)

example_plot(ax1)
example_plot(ax2)
example_plot(ax3)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: What do you mean "span multiple axes"?  As in multiple `Axes` objects? As in [some subplots are larger than others](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-and-subplotspec)?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question as a question? It's a bit difficult to tell precisely what you are asking.

Comment: Something like the second-to-last example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_tight_layout.html) (scroll down!)?

Comment: It's like that, cphlewis, but using a different invocation than I'm asking about. I've edited the question to clarify for both you and Eric Hauenstein

Comment: @user35050 Is there any reason you need to use `plt.subplots()`?  Are you just trying to write fewer lines? If the `Axes` objects are different sizes, you are much better off using [`gridspec`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-and-subplotspec)/[`gridspec` with variable cell sizes](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid) or [`subplot2grid`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid)

Comment: The reason that I want to use `plt.subplots()` is because that seems to be the most straightforward way to use them within the object-oriented interface, and I would like to have some consistency in the objects and functions I use to make these plots. If there is no such method using `plt.subplots()`, then I'll accept that as an answer, face the music, and learn the `gridspec` interface instead.

Comment: At the end of the day, they're all just different ways to get a collection of `Axes` objects.  **What is your actual use, i.e. how many subplots in a figure and in what arrangement?**  That will determine which approach is best for you.  But to my knowledge, you cannot specify anything akin to `colspan`/`rowspan` using `plt.subplots`.  The best you can probably do is specify `gridspec_kw` with different height/width ratios.