# Matplotlib graphing 2 graphs: 1 in polar and 1 in cartesian

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to plot 2 graphs (horizontally), and I'd like one to be a polar graph and the other cartesian. I have the following code which generates 2 cartesian graphs:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]
a = [2,3,4]
b = [5,7,5]

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols = 2)
ax1.scatter(x,y)
ax2.scatter(a,b)
plt.show()
```

Note these are just random points I chose.
How can I specify that I want, say the x-y plot, to be in polar?

Answer (score 7):

There unfortunately is no way to change the projection to polar on an existing axes, but you could do this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]
a = [2,3,4]
b = [5,7,5]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122, projection='polar')

ax1.scatter(x,y)
ax2.scatter(a,b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the difference between using plt.sublot() and plt.subplots()?

Comment: @Julian `subplots` can create an array of axes objects, where `subplot` only creates one subplot at a time, at the designated position in the grid, on which you can find a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3584933/7054628)