# Python: Set only 1/4 subplots as polar

Tags: python

[image]

I have an assignment where I am trying to replicate the following subplots

I successfully replicated the three non-polar plots, but I cannot figure out how to set the fourth plot to polar. Here is what I have so far with my code, only including code relevant to the polar plot.

```
nmax=101 # choose a high number to "smooth out" lines in plots
x = np.linspace(0,20,nmax) # create an array x
y = np.exp(-x/4)*np.sin(x) # y for the top two subplots

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

# bottom right subplot controls
axs[1, 1].polar(x, y)
```

This will give the error, `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'polar'`. How would I set the subplot to polar so I can replicate the plot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib graphing 2 graphs: 1 in polar and 1 in cartesian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064587/matplotlib-graphing-2-graphs-1-in-polar-and-1-in-cartesian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to define each axis separately, rather than using `plt.subplots`

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
ax3 = plt.subplot(223)
ax4 = plt.subplot(224, projection = 'polar')
```