# getting error when plotting with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.7

I am trying to plot using matplotlib with python 3.7.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor("green")
x = [3, 7, 8, 12]
y = [5, 13, 2, 8]
graph1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, axisbg="black")
graph1.plot(x, y, "red", linewidth=4.0)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 72, in __init__
  raise ValueError('Illegal argument(s) to subplot: %s' % (args,))

ValueError: Illegal argument(s) to subplot: (1, 1)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Could you fix the formatting of the error message please?

Comment: Relevant, but not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3584805/2988730

Comment: You can replace `fig.add_subplot(1,1,axisbg="black")` with `fig.add_subplot(111,axisbg="black")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`add_subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) has *three* mandatory arguments, not two. The arguments are M = "number of rows", N = "number of columns", and P = "item selection". The last one (P) is the linear index in the MxN grid, going across.

Additionally, the `axis_bg` and `axis_bgcolor` arguments were deprecated in matplotlib 2.0.0 and removed in matplotlib 2.2.0. Instead, use `facecolor` or `fc` for short.

You probably wanted to do

```
graph1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, fc="black")
```

That being said, if you want to create a single set of axes on a figure, I have generally found it easier to use [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to make the figure and axes in one shot:

```
fig, graph1 = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'facecolor': 'black'}, facecolor='green')
```

For convenience, it is most common to import [pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) as `plt`, either with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

or with

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

All combined, your code could end up looking like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, graph1 = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'facecolor': 'black'},
                           facecolor='green')

x = [3, 7, 8, 12]
y = [5, 13, 2, 8]
graph1.plot(x, y, "red", linewidth=4.0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: it gives me now the eror :Unknown property axisbg

Comment: @ElizaRomanski. The axis_bg axis_bgcolor were deprecated in matplotlib 2.0.0 and removed in matplotlib 2.2.0. Will update momentarily.

Comment: @ElizaRomanski because it only accepts only certain keyword arguments, [as per docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes): **kwargs This method also takes the keyword arguments for Axes.

Answer (score 0):

from [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html):

> add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)[source]
>
> Add a subplot.
>
> Call signatures:
>
> add_subplot(nrows, ncols, index, **kwargs)
>
> add_subplot(pos, **kwargs)

As far as I can tell you are not providing the `index` argument to the function.