# How to define figsize when plotting tree maps with squarify

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm plotting some [tree maps](https://python-graph-gallery.com/200-basic-treemap-with-python/) using [squarify](https://github.com/laserson/squarify).

I can't figure out how to define `figsize` for them though, nor I can find anything in their docs. Below the working code:

```
df = df.groupby(feature)["profit"].sum()
squarify.plot(sizes=df, label=df.index, alpha=.8)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

I've tried to add `figsize=(14, 6)` to `squarify.plot` as you can see below, but didn't work.

```
squarify.plot(sizes=df, label=df.index, figsize=(14, 6), alpha=.8)
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/laserson/squarify/blob/master/squarify/__init__.py) of the plot function looks like this:

> ```
> def plot(
>     sizes,
>     norm_x=100,
>     norm_y=100,
>     color=None,
>     label=None,
>     value=None,
>     ax=None,
>     pad=False,
>     bar_kwargs=None,
>     text_kwargs=None,
>     **kwargs
> ):
> ```

So the function takes an ax argument, which you can generate like this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
ax = fig.add_suplot(111)
```

then

```
squarify.plot(sizes=df, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I'm intrigued with something else. What's the trick with "111"? I've just looked at the docs and have seen the use of "111" there as well, but can't get it by the explanation of the parameters 

Comment: [Check this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html). 111 is shorthand for 1,1,1. This means you create a grid with 1 row, 1 column and go to the first plot, which in this case is the only one. 2,2,2 would mean you create a grid with 2 rows, 2 columns and go to plot 2, which is top-right

Comment: Also, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/in-matplotlib-what-does-the-argument-mean-in-fig-add-subplot111)