# Plot not showing x axis and y axis labels and values and chart title

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python just following a tutorial but the output is not same as expected `matplotlib` is not showing any thing on chart except the bars.

Here is the code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
packets = ['1.', '2', '3', '4', '5']
testTime = [2.3,1.7,3.5,2.9,1.2]
plt.bar(packets,testTime)
plt.ylabel('Responsi time (Seconds.milliseconds)')
plt.xlabel('Packets')
plt.title("Response Time")
plt.show()
```

Here is the output screenshot

[image]

Comment: As @eshirvana says, the problem is the line `fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])`, which is not necessary. But the reason it causes this to happen is because the actual plot takes up the full space of the image; change this line to `fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9])` and it will also work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by this `fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])` the axes will cover the whole plot, remove it or add a fraction (less than 1) , and you will be fine :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
# ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
packets = ['1.', '2', '3', '4', '5']
testTime = [2.3,1.7,3.5,2.9,1.2]
plt.bar(packets,testTime)
plt.ylabel('Responsi time (Seconds.milliseconds)')
plt.xlabel('Packets')
plt.title="Response Time"
plt.show()
```

output:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by [@eshirvana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367454/eshirvana):

If you don't know what fractions to use for `ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])`, however, you do need the axes `ax` (e.g. for subplots), you can do the following:

`ax = fig.add_subplot(111)`. This creates a grid of 1x1 and places the subplot at position 1 (a more detailed explanation of what the value passed to `add_subplot` means can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/what-does-the-argument-mean-in-fig-add-subplot111)).

The documentation of `add_subplot()` can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html). And an explanation for the